# Getting error installing Google Play services, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

First of all, I am a beginner at developing Android apps. I have run into a problem installing Google Play services into my project. I followed the instructions on the developers.google.com site for installing Google Play services SDK on my Android Studio. I then followed instructions on `developers.google.com` for adding service to my project. When it comes to syncing, I keep getting an error as shown in attached image. I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 and installed Google Play services ver 29.0.0. SDK. Attempting to install the Google Location, Activity Recognition, and Places API.
Can anyone help me with this issue, I am completely stuck on this.
[image: view image of error in Android Studio]

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: Yes I am behind a firewall!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because **version 29.0.0 doesn't exist**. The latest version is currently **8.4.0**.

Change

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:29.0.0
```

with

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
```

Pay attention.
What you are calling **v.29** is the version of **Google Repository** inside the SDK Manager, **not the version** of the **library** which is **8.4.0**.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your help.Problem is now fixed. Question, so how do i find the version number of the library. I am new to this so all help is welcomed, so I don't make this mistake again.

Comment: @user3649499 Fro the play services you can check the official site. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 0):

Following this [document](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/studio-config.html). Try this:

1. Setting up the Android Studio Proxy
2. Android Plugin for Gradle HTTP proxy settings

> Android Plugin for Gradle HTTP proxy settings
>
> When running the Android Plugin from the command line or on machines
>   where Android Studio is not installed, set the Android Plugin for
>   Gradle proxy settings in the Gradle build file. For
>   application-specific HTTP proxy settings, set the proxy settings in
>   the build.gradle file as required for each application module.
>
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
>       ...
>
> ```
> defaultConfig {
>     ...
>     systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.company.com
>     systemProp.http.proxyPort=443
>     systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
>     systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
>     systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=domain
> }
> ... }
> ```

Comment: @NNguyen Doan Tung....well thank you for trying, i followed instructions and i think i am more lost than i was before. It does not appear to have fixed issue.

Comment: I think the problem is the Gradle cannot connect to the server to get the package. So, following the instructions to setup proxy for your Android Studio may be a solution.

Comment: ..I will give it another try and get back to you, thank you for your time, it is appreciated.